# How to add App Icon in Live Wallpaper Android like normal Apps

Tags: android, icons, live, wallpaper

Is it possible to add an app icon , like it shows in Live Aquarium Wallpaper (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fishnoodle.aquarium_free&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImZpc2hub29kbGUuYXF1YXJpdW1fZnJlZSJd) 
When I install this wallpaper, it shows and icon which opens up the settings page when clicked on it. Has anyone done this before?

Comment: sorry the correct link is [https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anifree.anipet.aquarium.ad&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5hbmlmcmVlLmFuaXBldC5hcXVhcml1bS5hZCJd]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to declare an Activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml` with the default [intent-filter](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html):

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.your.company.ui.SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all you should create `Activity`:

```
public class SetLiveWallpaperActivity extends Activity{

@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16)
    {
        intent.setAction(WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER);
        intent.putExtra(WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT, new ComponentName(this, LibGDXWallpaperService.class));
    }
    else
    {
        intent.setAction(WallpaperManager.ACTION_LIVE_WALLPAPER_CHOOSER);
    }
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
  } 
}
```

Then in your `AndroidManifest.xml` you should add following code:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".SetLiveWallpaperActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.WallpaperSettings" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />               
        </intent-filter>           
 </activity>
```

It creates icon which opens up the settings page when clicked on it.
Hope it will help you or someone else.

Answer (score 0):

For those still looking for the correct answer:

You need to declare a `<meta-data>` tag, inside your declaration of  Wallpaper Service tag inside the manifest file:

```
    <service
        android:name=".MyWallpaperService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:label="My Wallpaper"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
            android:resource="@xml/wallpaper" >
        </meta-data>

    </service>
```

This tag points to an xml file which contains information about the icon of the wallpaper which appears in the Live-Wallpapers section:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wallpaper
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="GIF Wallpaper"
    android:thumbnail="@android:drawable/btn_star">
</wallpaper>
```

So `android:thumbnail` is where you set the resource for the icon